# all checkbox under a div not immediate inside to the div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have div with `id=”content”`

The div may contain a lot of

```
<input id="chkboxtag1" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
```

Div may contain `ul` tag. This `ul` may also contain check boxes. The div may contain divs or ul, it may also contain checkboxes.

Is there any chance that I get values of all checked check boxes inside the div (not necessarily immediate inside the div)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var selectedItems = new Array();

$('#content input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
       selectedItems.push($(this).val());
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
  alert($(this).val())
})
```

By this way, all checked checkboxes on you page will be "alerted" on screen.

See the [jQuery Selectors doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
var values = [];
$('#content input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) for this:

```
var arrayOfValues = $('#content input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {  
                      return this.value; 
                    }).get();
```

This gets an array of the values for the checked checkboxes under `<div id="content">`, you can use it as an array, or [`.join(', ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get a string...whatever use you want really.

Answer (score 1):

All above are answeres
i thought only immediate child is concodered
but Jquery is great!